# NGINX Remove index.php in URL Rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite, alias

i had to modify an NGINX configuration to allow getting the static files from a different folder.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.test;
    root "/home/vagrant/app/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location ~ (.*.css|.*.js|.*.png|.*.jpg|.*.gif|.*.svg) {
        alias /home/vagrant/app$request_uri;
    }

     location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
     }

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

The part i added was the `location .*.css` etc where it's basically matching those file extensions and if it finds them it serves them directly from a particular folder other that the main project folder.

Otherwise i want it to send PHP requests to the main project application, hence the location /.

It works alright, but the problem is that it shows the URL like `http://app.test/index.php/` whenever i try to navigate to `http://app.test/`, it wasn't doing that before i added the alias, and so i'm wondering if the alias could be the cause of it and how can i get rid of the added `index.php`. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your application is doing this, not nginx.

Comment: Hi, it was the browser actually, but you helped me figure it out, thank you :)